# how to query a extjs 4 store?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

how to write a function to multiply two column values and set result to third column and loop this for all records for each add, delete, edit actions?

i tried to use store's **add**, **remove**, and **update** *events* and 
then set value to third column and commit changes. 
problem is, its going in a never ending loop since as soon as i set value and then commit,
it fires the update event and call the function again.

any idea how to do this properly?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this [Ext.grid.column.Column.renderer](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer). Something like :

```
renderer: function(value, meta, record){
    return record.get('val1')+record.get('val2');
}
```

After you added, removed or updated something just do store.load() and you should be fine!!

p.s. you want to submit the third value back ?

Comment: calling store.load() can not be done though, im using a store with memory proxy.